# Ignoring Hidden Files with File::Find

Tags: perl, find

I am using `file::find` to walk a directory structure and print it out, but I am having trouble excluding hidden files. Here is what I have so far:

```
find(\&todo, $start_dir);
sub todo 
{
  if ($_ =~ /^./) 
  {
     print "hidden file $_\n";
  }
  else
  {
    if (-f $_) #check for file
    {
      file;
    }
    elsif (-d $_) #check for directory
    {
      directory($File::Find::dir);
    }
    else
    {
       print "ERROR: $_\n";
    }
  }
}
```

If I remove the `if ($_ =~ /^./)` check, the files and directories work fine, but adding this prints everything as a hidden file. As you can see, I only need this to work on unix. 
Can anyone point me in the right direction?

EDIT: I forgot a backslash in front of the . - should be if ($_ =~ /^./), but does find() have a default way of ignoring hidden files/directories?
Thanks!

Comment: This ended up working:
if (!(($_ =~ /^\./) || ($File::Find::dir =~ m/[.]/)))

Answer (score 8):

`.` in a regex matches any character; use `\.` to match a literal `.`.  And you probably should [learn about regexes](https://encrypted.google.com/search?q=regex%20introduction&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8).

Comment: Thanks. I'll be sure to read up. I feel like Perl probably has a better way to just ignore hidden files using find(), but I haven't found any ways by searching...does that functionality not exist?

Comment: `File::Find` just gives you files, and it's up to your `wanted` function to select the ones you want.  It makes no attempt to handle anything other than automatically recursing into directories.

Answer (score 2):

See geekosaur for an explanation of your problem. In a simple case like this, [`substr`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/substr.html) might be a better call than a regular expression:

```
if(substr($_, 0, 1) eq '.') {
```

Regular expressions are a great tool but they shouldn't be the only thing in your toolbox.

Comment: Thanks, this accomplishes the same thing right? My problem now is that it still goes through the hidden directories...is there a way to modify find() to ignore hidden files/directories?

Comment: @Ryan: It accomplishes the same thing as `if($_ =~ /^\./)`. And I think geekosaur is sorting you out on how `File::Find` works, right?

Answer (score 1):

The `/^./` is a [regular expression](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html). The period means any single character, so what you're saying is *match any string that starts with any character*, and that pretty much matches all file names.

You need to put a backslash before the period, or use the `\Q` and '\E'. The `\Q` disables matching on *metacharacters* which means it basically removes all magic and makes everything a plain ol' string. In this circumstance, the backslash would be better, but you can imagine trying to match something a bit more complex, and the `\Q` and `\E` would work better:

Either of these will work:

```
 if ($_ =~ /^\./) 
 {
     print "hidden file $_\n";
 }


 if ($_ =~ /^\Q.\E/) 
 {
     print "hidden file $_\n";
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are on Windows the perl module [Win32::File](http://search.cpan.org/~gsar/libwin32-0.191/File/File.pm) will tell you whether a file is hidden or not. Win32::File is installed by default in ActivePerl.

Unfortunately Win32::File doesn't come with any examples, *(I wish cpan added a comment feature to every page like the PHP site. Sure there's Annocpan, but that extra click means almost no one ever contributes to it)*, but this thread will help http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=194011

There's also the nicer object oriented [Win32::File::Object](http://search.cpan.org/~adamk/Win32-File-Object-0.02/lib/Win32/File/Object.pm) but it only works with files unless you apply this patch :( https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=60735

Results seem weird though as lots of files you don't except to be hidden or system turn out to be both. I gave up in the end and just hacked this to ignore certain folders:

```
if( $_ =~ /(RECYCLER)|(System Volume Information)/ ) {
    $File::Find::prune = 1;
}
```